# How to add or remove buttons to editable jquery datatables based on certain conditionals

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

I am using editable jquery datatables inside a .js file but when initializing the datatable, I want to be able to add buttons based on conditions. For example, if user only has Update access right but not Delete, only show Update button.

So I have two options, either be able to add the buttons based on those conditions or be able to remove the button completely after initializing the datatable instead of only hiding it.

What I have tried: I had no luck finding anything to try for the first option (adding buttons only when conditions are met) For the second option, I tried using CSS visibility and adding both buttons and later hiding one but if I only need the second one, the "placeholder" for the first (hidden) button makes the second button seem floating to the right.

Are there any other options or methods I can use?

Answer (score 0):

Someone else asked a similar question after I posted mine and the answer to that answered my question as well so I'm posting a link in case someone stumbled upon this one and had the same issue.

The solution was to use the fact that the buttons is an array and push the required buttons when the condition is met.

[How to conditionally display TableTools buttons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30921073/how-to-conditionally-display-tabletools-buttons)