# Hide a button in jquery based on user access

Tags: javascript, jquery, spring-security

I'm trying to hide a button. If it was on the html i would simply do

```
<security:authorize access="hasAuthority('Administrator')">
//html button code
</security:authorize>
```

but my `delete button` is being generated from datatable.

```
 var table = $('#dataTable').DataTable({
    language: {
        searchPlaceholder: "Search...",
        emptyTable: "There are no available flows."
    },
    columnDefs: [ {
        orderable: false,
        className: 'select-checkbox',
        targets:   0
    },
        {type: "date-euro", targets: 7},
        {type: "date-euro", targets: 8}
    ],
    order: [[1, 'desc']],
    select: {
        style:    'multi',
        selector: 'td:first-child'
    },
    lengthChange: false,
    dom: 'Bfrtip',
    buttons: [
        {
            text: '<span class="fa fa-plus"></span> Create',
            className: 'btn-primary-outline',
            action: function () {
                location.href = "create-flow";
            }
        },
        {
            text: '<span class="fa fa-trash"></span> Delete',
            className: 'btn-danger-outline',
            action: function () {
                console.log($('#hasAuthority').val());
                var selectedRows = table.rows({selected: true});
                if (selectedRows.nodes().length > 0) {
                    //Get names
                    var data = selectedRows.data();
                    var names = [];
                    $.each(data, function (index, value) {
                        names.push(value[2]);
                    });
                    //Remove them
                    $.ajax({
                        url: '/flow/delete?names=' + names,
                        type: 'delete',
                        success: function () {
                            //reload page
                            location.reload();
                        }
                    });
                    //de-select selected rows
                    table.rows('.selected').deselect();
                }
            }
        }
    ]
});
```

I'm trying to give a value to a input if user is admin or not but I'm getting undefined

```
<security:authorize access="hasAuthority('Administrator')" var="hasAuthority"></security:authorize>
<input type="hidden" id="hasAuthority" value="${hasAuthority}">
```

But then how do I corporate the `if(hasAuthority)` only on the delete button? The syntax doesn't match.

Comment: And showing/hiding it with javascript instead of using `type=hidden`?

Comment: lol.. I mean hide completely from the user if he is not admin.

Comment: Well in that case check this question, I think it fits your needs: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30921073/how-to-conditionally-display-tabletools-buttons

Comment: ok I fixed and i'm not getting undefined anymore but how do I integrate the if($('#hasAuthority').val() === "true") here?

Comment: @IgnacioAra thanks that worked.